# What exactly decides the TTC frequency selections of X-band for deep space missions, C band for geostationary , and S band for LEO missions?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, radio-frequency

Data rates are higher in X-band, but considering free space path loss and atmospheric attenuation(diffraction I'm assuming is significant here), won't lower frequencies stand a better chance? Again, cost and weight is a factor, but I want to understand the physics that goes behind these selections.
Additionally, why do uplink and downlink frequencies differ in which one is higher?(Uplink is higher in the case of C and X band whereas it's lower in S band)

Comment: Except for a few bands, such as the ones that are in the oxygen or water absorption resonances. the allocation for one or anther frequency use is not based on any technical rational but almost always political reality, that includes anything in the S, C or X bands.